# How does Lee Sin fall off late-game?

Tags: league-of-legends

How does Lee Sin fall off late-game?

Everyone says it, but I don't see how.

Is there any way to prevent it?

Answer (score 3):

From my experience playing against and as him, he falls of due to his build, his team fighting abilities, and his abilities failure to scale well into late game.  This doesn't mean that a Lee Sin can't own late game some games, just if the teams have comparable setups and the games pretty even.

Usually he's built pretty tanky with some decent damage, but no crazy damage, crit, or attack speed.  This makes him a good initiator and good at chasing down people, but he doesn't have the cc or survivebility to tank or instigate team fights, and doesn't do enough damage to burn through enemy champs quickly.

I wouldn't even say he's bad late game, it's just that his play style has to change.  You go from instigating fights and fearing no one, to waiting till a team fight starts and them jumping on the carrys in the back.

Lee Sin is a shit load of fun though, just loses that unstoppable feeling after you get 30-40 mins in...

Answer (score 0):

He's strong. If he does fall off, its a very small percentage. He's by far the strongest jungle in the game because of his incredible ganking potential. The only way to prevent it is to build straight AD carry, which i dont recommend.

I build him Wriggle's Lantern into a Warmogs/Atmas combo, unless im getting super fed, then I go Trinity Force after the wriggles.

Answer (score -1):

Lee Sin in my experience is like a lot of other champs, you need to farm well, don't feed and get the correct set of items depending on the enemy.

But he is stronger than other melee champs, like Renekton.