# Champions that dominate early, only to fall of late game

Tags: league-of-legends

There are several champions that i have been playing that seem insanely strong early,only to fall off hard late game such as xin zhao,lee sin and renekton.

What other champions of these kind are there and what contributes to the factors that cause them to be less effective late game?

Comment: nvm sorry,just found a extremely similar question.Close it please.

Comment: you know you can personally remove the question?

Comment: @marco Geertsma how? only has options share,edit and flag.Do i edit and delete everything?

Comment: made an answer on how to remove ;)

Comment: @person Might be more usefull to link the question you've found. In that case, we could flag.

Comment: @joetjah http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/94896/what-exactly-defines-a-champ-who-falls-off-late

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I had to tell you: Jungler : Maokai; APC:Leblanc; ADC: Urgot.

Especially Leblanc. She's able to safely trade damage with the lane opponent, and kill anyway before lvl 8. Her main problem is her hardcore CS issue. The only AOE spell for csing is her escape (so, not a good idea overall) and her auto attack is weak and slow.